# Linear Algebra help null space = column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that A is a square matrix whose column space is equal to its null space. Show
that A^2 must be the zero matrix.

I`m pretty stuck . Does the solution have something to do with the inverse of the square matrix being zero?

Comment: If column space of $\mathbf{A}$ is equal to the null-space, then $\mathbf{AA}=0$ since you're multiplying $\mathbf{A}$ by something on the right but you know that the null-space and the column-space to be the same. So infer why $\mathbf{AA}=0$ from the last statement.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* For any $v$, $Av$ is in the column space of $A$ and hence the null space of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be any vector. Then either $Ax = 0$, or $Ax$ is in a column space. In both of these cases, what can you say about $A^2x = A(Ax)$? Keep in mind, this works for **any** vector $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to do with the inverse, because the matrix need not be square. Think of it this way. The column space of a matrix spans the range of $A$. In other words, $Ax$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$ through the definition of matrix multiplication. The problem states that the null-space is equal to the column space. That means that any vector in the column space belongs to the null-space...